Scraping data from data.census.gov county profiles
I'm trying to write a program using bs4 (or another method) that can scrape the data from the title pages of specific counties, like this one: https://data.census.gov/profile/Grant_County,_New_Mexico?g=050XX00US35017#populations-and-people
I want to be able to retrieve those nine statistics that are in the title page without having to go through the respective CSVs of origin and re-calculate those values. I have only ever scraped data from simple HTMLs Wikipedia, and am unsure of how to do it when the numbers don't appear to be immediately visible in the html of the webpage (maybe I need some java knowledge here, too...?) Thanks for any tips/nudges in the right direction!
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


census.gov maintains APIs for developers--it is far easier and faster to get data from an API than via web scraping

(1) first check if page has API and if it has function to get data which you need - it will be much simpler because it will gives only data without HTML. (2) if there is no API then check if page use JavaScript to add elements - because requests and BeautifulSoup can't run JavaScript and it may need Selenium which can control real web browser which can run JavaScript. (3) check page in private mode because it may use some cookies or your logins  which you made earlier - but BeautifulSoup doesn't have these information and it may need get it.

this page uses JavaScript. When I turn off JavaScript in browser and reload page then i see empty page. And the same see BeautifulSoup. So you can't get it with BeautifulSoup

Try something like this:
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
}

params = {
    # Grant County, New Mexico
    'g': '050XX00US35017',
    # Los Angeles County, California
    # 'g': '050XX00US06037',
}

response = requests.get(
    'https://data.census.gov/api/profile/content/highlights',
    params=params,
    headers=headers
)

print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2))

The county is specified via g parameter in the params dictionary. You'll find this identifier in the URL. For example:

https://data.census.gov/profile/Grant_County,_New_Mexico?g=050XX00US35017
https://data.census.gov/profile/Los_Angeles_County,_California?g=050XX00US06037

This is what the data looks like for Grant County.
{
  "selectedProfile": {
    "label": "Grant County, New Mexico",
    "params": {
      "g": "050XX00US35017"
    }
  },
  "highlights": [
    {
      "format": "number",
      "value": "28185",
      "topic": "Populations and People",
      "label": "Total Population",
      "sourceLink": "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/decennial-census/about/rdo.html",
      "source": "2020 Decennial Census",
      "tableId": "DECENNIALPL2020.P1"
    },
    {
      "format": "dollar",
      "value": "44895",
      "topic": "Income and Poverty",
      "label": "Median Household Income",
      "sourceLink": "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs.html",
      "source": "2022 American Community Survey 5-Year Estimates",
      "tableId": "ACSST5Y2022.S1901"
    },
    {
      "format": "percent",
      "value": "26.4",
      "topic": "Education",
      "label": "Bachelor's Degree or Higher",
      "sourceLink": "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs.html",
      "source": "2022 American Community Survey 5-Year Estimates",
      "tableId": "ACSST5Y2022.S1501"
    },
    {
      "format": "percent",
      "value": "41.9",
      "topic": "Employment",
      "label": "Employment Rate",
      "sourceLink": "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs.html",
      "source": "2022 American Community Survey 5-Year Estimates",
      "tableId": "ACSDP5Y2022.DP03"
    },
    {
      "format": "number",
      "value": "14584",
      "topic": "Housing",
      "label": "Total Housing Units",
      "sourceLink": "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/decennial-census/about/rdo.html",
      "source": "2020 Decennial Census",
      "tableId": "DECENNIALPL2020.H1"
    },
    {
      "format": "percent",
      "value": "5.1",
      "topic": "Health",
      "label": "Without Health Care Coverage",
      "sourceLink": "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs.html",
      "source": "2022 American Community Survey 5-Year Estimates",
      "tableId": "ACSST5Y2022.S2701"
    },
    {
      "format": "number",
      "value": "534",
      "topic": "Business and Economy",
      "label": "Total Employer Establishments",
      "sourceLink": "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/cbp.html",
      "source": "2021 Economic Surveys Business Patterns",
      "tableId": "CBP2021.CB2100CBP"
    },
    {
      "format": "number",
      "value": "11292",
      "topic": "Families and Living Arrangements",
      "label": "Total Households",
      "sourceLink": "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs.html",
      "source": "2022 American Community Survey 5-Year Estimates",
      "tableId": "ACSDP5Y2022.DP02"
    },
    {
      "format": "number",
      "value": "13466",
      "topic": "Race and Ethnicity",
      "label": "Hispanic or Latino (of any race)",
      "sourceLink": "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/decennial-census/about/rdo.html",
      "source": "2020 Decennial Census",
      "tableId": "DECENNIALDHC2020.P9"
    }
  ]
}

If you want to get the area from the descriptor paragraph (see comment below) then you can add this:
params = {
    'g': '050XX00US35017',
    'includeHighlights': 'false',
}

response = requests.get(
    "https://data.census.gov/api/profile/metadata",
    params=params,
    headers=headers
)

print(response.json()["header"]["description"])

That will return the complete paragraph text and you'll need to use string operation to extract the area.

Super! Please accept the answer.

How did you know where to find this link? https://data.census.gov/api/profile/content/highlights

And is there a way to also scrape the square mileage of each county? That's located in the little descriptor paragraph in the beginning.

I used the Network tab in Developer Tools to find the URL for the API behind the site.

Updated my answer with how to grab that metadata paragraph.
